# How to track down a mystery autocompletion

Tags: mojave, auto-complete

Every time I type

```
nvm install
```

it magically autocompletes to

```
nvm install 9.2.1 --reinstall-packages-from=9.2.0 --latest-npm
```

with a return at the end, which errors as I'm using node 10.12.0 these days.

It doesn't matter what app I type this into, terminal, text editor, or even the browser (it autocompleted above when I typed this).

I've never set up any such autocompletion rules, and this wasn't happening previously.  How could this happen and how do I stop it?

Running `macOS 10.14` (Mojave)

Answer (score 1):

Argh.  Found the culprit.  [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) was doing it.

[image]

Looks like it was me after all.  *sigh*.